# Tracking Response Time in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am wanting to write a program in Shiny that will keep up with the response time taken to interact with various objects. The simplest analogue would be something like a timed matching game wherein the user must select a specific object/stimulus, and I want to be able to find out later (i.e., after the application is finished) how long each response took and whether it was correct.

I already know how to do most of this program; however, I cannot find anyway within Shiny to keep up with response time let alone as a function of interaction with a reactive element. Based on preliminary searches, it seems like Javascript may have a solution; however, I know zero Javascript experience and also don't have any experience integrating it with Shiny.

Does anyone know of a way of using existing R/Shiny language to perform a count-up timer that could be used to time responses to multiple objects? Alternatively, does anyone have a potentially better solution to timing responses that I may be missing?

**EDIT: ABOVE ISSUE ADDRESSED, BUT NEW ONE HAS COME UP IN AN EXTENSION OF THE ANSWER**

I initially left this as a comment, but it was too long to fit in the length requirements. I've come up with a new issue. This time, I want to keep a running tab of how long it has taken between any two clicks but without knowing how many clicks a user may submit. I've played around some with the code given, but I can't get it to work (relevant pieces below, nothing else was changed):

```
if(total_timestamps == 2){
     duration <- rbind(duration, as.numeric(difftime(new_val[2],new_val[1],units = "secs")))
     new_val[1] <- new_val[2]
     new_val <- new_val[-2, ]
     click_timestamps(new_val)
           ### other things to do 
  }
```

My thought was to switch the old and new values and then delete the oldest value to make room for a new one to continue the cycle, but it's not working as I had hoped. Thoughts or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. You can create a reactive value, and append value to it each time an element is clicked. If you need to observe multiple different elements, then just write more observers.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button","Click"),
  tags$h2("Response Time"),
  tags$div(id = "duration")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    click_timestamps <- reactiveVal(NULL)
    observeEvent(input$button,{
        new_val <- append(click_timestamps(),Sys.time())
        # set click timestamp
        click_timestamps(new_val)

        total_timestamps <- length(new_val)
        if(total_timestamps == 2){
            duration <- as.numeric(difftime(new_val[2],new_val[1],units = "secs"))
            insertUI(
                selector = "#duration",
                ui = tags$p(paste0("Seconds between clicks: ", duration))
            )
            # reset click timestamp
            click_timestamps(NULL)
        }



    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]